# Removing second element of a list

Tags: python-3.x

I was working on some code which has a list of integers such as list1 = [1,2,3,4,5] , I want to print out `1 3 4 5` so just print out a "new list" without second element.

Comment: deans7 please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) any one answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use indexes properly with [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) (I assume you want to keep the original list intact):

```
>>> list1[0:1] + list1[2:]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

So in general to skip the `i` element (when `0` is included):

```
>>> list1[0:i] + list1[i+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

A more scalable solution is to provide the index location of the original list that you would like to exclude.  Then [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) over that list and exclude values at the relevant index location.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
excluded_index = [1]
new_list = [i for n, i in enumerate(list1) if n not in excluded_index]
>>> new_list
[1, 3, 4, 5]

excluded_index = [1, 3]
>>> [i for n, i in enumerate(list1) if n not in excluded_index]
 [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use del and specify the element you want to delete with the index:

`del [index]`

`del list1[1];` will print `1 3 4 5`

**Note : `del` , will delete element from list , so be careful if you think you need your list intact for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the second element can be done by array slicing. Then using the join string method.

```
removed = list1[0:1] + list1[2:]
print(' '.join([str(x) for x in removed]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do a simple pop operation which is inbulit in python.

```
>>list1.pop(1)
>>[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

it will result [1, 3, 4, 5] which will be stored in list1